# How to keep decoding alive during screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Folks,

I am using MediaCodec to decode a network stream. Method configure() on MediaCodec takes a SurfaceView object as a parameter, making it easy to decode the output directly into the surface view.

The problem comes in when the device orientation is changed. The old surface gets destroyed and a new surface is created. The surface that mediacodec is still holding becomes invalid.

I cannot destroy MediaCodec object and recreate a new one. This would result in waiting for a few more seconds until a new key video frame arrives.

Looking at all the methods that are available on MediaCodec, it appears the only way to change the surface is by calling configure(). Is it okay to call configure() multiple times on the MediaCodec object?

Or, perhaps there is a way to store the internal state of the MediaCodec object and transfer it to a new MediaCodec object.

I would appreciate it if you can guide me in the right direction. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The set of allowed operations on `MediaCodec` objects is a bit vague.  An alternative approach would be to configure a `Surface` that isn't tied to the display, e.g. a `SurfaceTexture` that you would then render into a `GLSurfaceView` with OpenGL ES.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give SurfaceTexture a try.

Comment: You can try TextureView," Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc. For instance, you can make a TextureView semi-translucent by calling myView.setAlpha(0.5f)." My problem is I can't decode h264 frame successfully by using Mediacodec,maybe you can give me some help,my email is zhang.wei@gvconcepts.com ,thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There's now an example of this in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  See the "Double decode" activity.

It works by directing the output of the video decoder to a `SurfaceTexture` instead of directly to a view.  The `SurfaceTexture` is attached to a `TextureView`.  When the views change because of device rotation, a new `TextureView` is created, and we drop in the old `SurfaceTexture` with the [setSurfaceTexture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html#setSurfaceTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) method.

If you leave the activity with "back" or "home", the decoders are shut down.  This is useful to avoid tying up hardware codec resources when switching to other apps.

It currently doesn't shut the decoders down if you turn the screen off with the power key, which may or may not be desirable.

To make life interesting, it decodes two streams side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have solved the setting surface and `IllegalStateException` issues on orientation problem using your idea. Thanks for the great **Grafika**

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you set your activity to handle device orientation in manifest to keep your activity alive?.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config