# Video decoder Configure using MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am trying to decode video samples using MediaCodec API. I am using surfaceView to show rendered samples. If i press home button, app going into pause state and surface destroyed. When i coming back to resume state, new surfaceView reference is creating, but decoder is unable to pump samples on surfaceView. so screen appearing as black.
video configure:
videoDecoder.configure(format, surface, null, 0);
So how can i reconfigure videoDecoder in above statement. It is similar to the following problem
[How to keep decoding alive during screen orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236498/android-how-to-keep-decoding-alive-during-screen-orientation)

Answer (score 3):

The `MediaCodec` API does not currently (API 19) provide a way to replace the output `Surface`.

As in the other question you refer to, I think the way to deal with this will be to decode to a `Surface` that isn't tied to the view hierarchy (and, hence, doesn't get torn down when the `Activity` is destroyed).

If you direct the output of the `MediaCodec` to a `SurfaceTexture`, you can then render that texture onto the `SurfaceView`.  This will require a bit of GLES code.  You can find the necessary pieces in the [Grafika sources](https://github.com/google/grafika/), but there isn't currently a full implementation of what you want (e.g. `PlayMovieActivity` decodes video to a `SurfaceTexture`, but that ST is part of a `TextureView`, which will get torn down).

The additional rendering step will increase the GPU load, and won't work for DRM-protected video.  For most devices and apps this won't matter.

See also the [bigflake examples](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

**Update:** I've added this to [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), with a twist.  See the "Double decode" example.  The output goes to a `SurfaceTexture` associated with a `TextureView`.  If the screen is rotated (or, currently, blanked by hitting the power button), decoding continues.  If you leave the activity with the "back" or "home" button, decoding stops.  It works by retaining the `SurfaceTexture`, attaching it to the new `TextureView`.

Comment: Hi fadden thanks for your response. Can you give some example codes.

Comment: I won't be updating bigflake/grafika in the next couple of weeks.  BTW, if you're pulling video from a file with `MediaExtractor` (rather than streaming H.264), then you should be able to recreate the extractor/decoder after the activity restarts and just seek to the position where you left off.  The time offset can be determined from the presentation time stamp.

Comment: Thanks fadden. I will change my code according to your suggestion.

Comment: @fadden I have used DoubleDecode Activity in my app, it's working very smoothly. Do you know how can I add sound to video in it?